# Let $M$ be a left $R$-module, every epimorphism $f:M\rightarrow R$ splits.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, epimorphisms

This problem comes from a exercise of Rings and Categories of Modules.

Let $M$ be a left $R$-module, proof that every epimorphism $f:M \rightarrow R$ splits.

(If $f:M \rightarrow N $ and $f':N \rightarrow M$ are homomorphisms with $ff'$= $1_N$, we say that $f$ is a split epimorphism.)

My first idea is :

For $\forall r\in R$, I choose $m\in M$ which satifies $f\left( m \right) =r$.

Then I define $$f':R\rightarrow M$$  $$f'(r)=m$$.

I would like to know if the idea is correct? Perhaps I  do not think well.

From the Comment section, I get the following picture.

$R$ is a free $R$-module, so $R$ is a projection module, so exists $f':R\rightarrow M$ which satisfies $ff'=1_R$.

THanks!
[image]

Comment: Is $R$ a ring with $1$?

Comment: Should that say $f'f = 1_M$? See https://eloisagrifo.github.io/CHAnotes.pdf page 28 for the phrase "\phi splits" with the opposite composition

Comment: @peter Yes, $R$ has a identity element

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused  No , only satisfies $ff'=1_N$.

Comment: $R$ is free as a left module over itself. Figure out where to send $1$, the rest should follow.

Comment: Your idea does not work in general, because it need not be a module morphism. E.g., say $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=R\times R$, and $f$ is the projection on the first coordinate. I pick a preimage of $2$ to be $(2,0)$, and for $4$ I pick $(4,1)$. Then $f'(2+2)\neq f'(2)+f'(2)$.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin Thanks! From your comment, I get $R$ is a free $R$-module, so  $R$ is a projection module, then there exists $f'$ which satisfies $ff'=1_R$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true in general for a projective object ($R$-module). A projective $R$-module is one which is a direct summand of a free-$R$-module (that is, a direct sum of copies of $R$). In particular, free modules are projective (but not conversely!!) An equivalent definition of a $R$-module $N$ to be projective is that given any homomorphism $N \to A$ and an epimorphism $B \to A$ (where $A$ and $B$ are $R$-modules), there is a homomorphism $N \to B$ such that the composition $N \to B \to A$ = $N \to A$.

Since $R$ is a free $R$-module, it is projective. Take the identity map from $R \to R$ and the given epimorphism $M \to R$. The projectivity of $R$ would give you an arrow $R \to M$ which is a section of the epimorphism $M \to R$. To see what this section is explicitly, you can follow the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for any linear map $g: M \to R^n$, and the proof is just like the familiar one from linear algebra.

Recall that $R^n$ has the standard ordered basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$.
Because $g$ is surjective, then for each standard basis element $e_j$ there exists an element $m_j \in M$ such that $g(m_j)=e_j$. Now just define $f(e_j) := m_j$ for each $1 \leq j \leq n$, and extend by linearity to a map $f: R^n \to M$, i.e.
$$f(x) := \Sigma_{j=1}^n x_j f(e_j)=\Sigma_{j=1}^n x_j m_j.$$
Then it follows that
$$g(f(x)) = g \left( \Sigma_{j=1}^n x_j m_j \right) = \Sigma_{j=1}^n x_j g(m_j) = \Sigma_{j=1}^n x_j e_j = x. $$